# When updating a user profile, some info gets erased from DB, Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When i update my user profile, the field vicinity which is inside of location on my user model gets erased, this is my user model, where you can see vicinity inside location:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({

  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please supply a name',
    trim: true
  },
   location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: [{
      type: Number,
      required: 'You must supply coordinates!'
    }],
    address: {
      type: String,
      required: 'You must supply an address!'
    },
    vicinity: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
});
```

Then i have a controller which updates the user, where i have an updates object, and the vicinity is not threre, as i do not wish to update it, i just want to save the vicinity on register, not update it:

```
exports.updateAccount = async (req, res) => {
  req.body.location.type = 'Point';

  const updates = {
    email: req.body.email,
    name: req.body.name,
    photo: req.body.photo,
    genres: req.body.genres,
    musicLinks: req.body.musicLinks,
    location: {
      type: req.body.location.type,
      coordinates: [
        req.body.location.coordinates[0],
        req.body.location.coordinates[1],
      ],
      address: req.body.location.address,
      // vicinity: req.body.location.vicinity,
    }
  };

  if(!updates.photo) delete updates.photo

  const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.user._id },
    { $set: updates },
    { new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query' }
  );
  req.flash('success', 'Updated the profile!');
  res.redirect('back');
};
```

But everytime i update the user profile, the vicinity field gets erased, also note that, in the form where i submit the update for the user  there is no field for vicinity, so it is not sending any data to update.

Im guessing that because on the controller i have an updates object like:

```
 location: {
      type: req.body.location.type,
      coordinates: [
        req.body.location.coordinates[0],
        req.body.location.coordinates[1],
      ],
      address: req.body.location.address,
      // vicinity: req.body.location.vicinity,
    }
```

and its missing vecinity. the database tries to save the whole location object, and as there is no vicinity it gets erased.

If that is the case.. how do i say to mongo db to keep the value on the db and not delete it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having this is that you're actually updating `location` field with a new object. Every key under `location` object is erased and then rewritten - that's why `vicinity` is lost.

To accomplish your goal, you can use nested key syntax:

```
const updates = {
  $set: {
    email: req.body.email,
    name: req.body.name,
    photo: req.body.photo,
    genres: req.body.genres,
    musicLinks: req.body.musicLinks,
    'location.type': req.body.location.type,
    'location.coordinates': [req.body.location.coordinates[0], req.body.location.coordinates[1]],
    'location.address': req.body.location.address,
  }
};
```

After that:

```
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.user._id },
  updates,
  { new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query' }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's by design.

You actually include a "full object" for `location` in your arguments to [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/), and this **does** simply *overwrite* that object. That's basically how MongoDB works.

The other part of how MongoDB works is when it is your intent to *partially* update a document with "nested paths", you need to process that object structure into ["Dot Notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) form.

In fact, here's a basic version of something I put together a long time ago to do exactly that:

```
var data = {
    email: "bill@example.com",
    name: "Bill S Preston",
    photo: "",
    genres: "Music, Lyrics",
    musicLinks: "",
    location: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [
        0,
        0
      ],
      address: "somewhere"
    }
};
```

And a simple function:

```
function dotNotate(obj,target,prefix) {
  target = target || {},
  prefix = prefix || "";

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if ( Array.isArray(obj[key] )) {
      return target[prefix + key] = obj[key];
    } else if ( typeof(obj[key]) === "object" ) {
      dotNotate(obj[key],target,prefix + key + ".");
    } else {
      return target[prefix + key] = obj[key];
    }
  });

  return target;
}
```

Running that function produces:

```
var updates = dotNotate(data);

{
        "email" : "bill@example.com",
        "name" : "Bill S Preston",
        "photo" : "",
        "genres" : "Music, Lyrics",
        "musicLinks" : "",
        "location.type" : "Point",
        "location.coordinates" : [
                0,
                0
        ],
        "location.address" : "somewhere"
}
```

And of course `{ $set: updates }` will only *partially update* the fields explicitly specified without overwriting.

Comment: How do i use your function? I assume obj is the data.. but what should i put in the target and prefix parameters? Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @GiorgioMartini You don't **need** to unless you specifically wanted to do it ( i.e nest within *another* object ). Your usage as per the example shown in the answer simply needs provide the whole object from the request as you are currently fetching. Those additional function arguments are *mostly* there because it's **recursive** and works through multiple depths.